# How to use icons with NavigationProvider that are not Material Design?

Tags: c#, icons, customization, font-awesome, aspnetboilerplate

I would like to use icons with the `NavigationProvider` that are not available in the [material design offerings](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline).

Inside the `SetNavigation` method, we build up the Main Menu.

There is an option to set the `icon` property by using the Material Design icon name — for example, the menu item below uses the `"people"` string to display the png:

[image]

```
.AddItem(
    new MenuItemDefinition(
        PageNames.Doctors,
        L("Doctors"),
        url: "Doctors",
        icon: "people",
        requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Doctors
    )
)
```

Can other icons be used besides the material design ones? If so, how do I reference the image or icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ASP.NET Core + Angular

Modify the following in **sidebar-nav.component.ts**:

```js
// new MenuItem(this.l("HomePage"), "", "home", "/app/home"),
new MenuItem(this.l("HomePage"), "", "fa fa-home", "/app/home"),
```

Modify the following in **sidebar-nav.component.html**:

```html
<!-- <i *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</I> -->
<i *ngIf="menuItem.icon && menuItem.icon.startsWith('fa ')" class="{{menuItem.icon}}"></i>
<i *ngIf="menuItem.icon && !menuItem.icon.startsWith('fa ')" class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</I>
```

You may want to add some **Styling** (see below) in **sidebar-nav.component.html**.

## ASP.NET Core + jQuery

Modify the following in ***NavigationProvider.cs**:

```cs
new MenuItemDefinition(
    PageNames.Home,
    L("HomePage"),
    url: "",
 // icon: "home",
    icon: "fa fa-home",
    requiresAuthentication: true
)
```

Modify the following in **SideBarNav/Default.cshtml**:

```html
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(menuItem.Icon))
{
    <!-- <i class="material-icons">@menuItem.Icon</i> -->
    @if (menuItem.Icon.StartsWith("fa "))
    {
        <i class="@menuItem.Icon"></i>
    }
    else
    {
        <i class="material-icons">@menuItem.Icon</i>
    }
}
```

You may want to add some **Styling** (see below) in **SideBarNav/Default.cshtml**.

## Styling

```html
<style>
    .sidebar .fa {
        font-size: 24px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 24px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use font awesome as well like below

```
AddItem(new MenuItemDefinition(
    PageNames.App.Tenant.Google,
    new FixedLocalizableString("Google"),
    icon : "fa fa-bar-chart",
    requiredPermissionName : AppPermissions.Pages_Google,
    url : "http://www.google.com",
    target : "_blank"
    )
)
```

Comment: unfortunately fa does not work with the MenuItemDefinition class - i thought it would but have tried a few and no luck.

Comment: add font-awesome to your project. in this issue the guy used fa icons as well. https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2428

Comment: cheers,  @arron got me going by introducing some logic in the view to use fa or material depending on the name of the icon.